# How would I get audio input to a pi pico?

Tags: audio, pi-pico, micropython, usb-audio, circuitpython

I’m trying to make an audio visualiser with the pi pico, and I want to connect it to my computer. I need to read the audio from the computer to do this.

I could use an audio jack, but I can’t find much documentation or boards that let you do this.
I tried to find something about audio input over USB, but I couldn’t find anything.

I’m using micropython, however I can switch to any pico language if necessary.

I just want to be pointed in the right direction to something that can help me do this.

Comment: Analog audio jacks (the norm) are, surprise, analog inputs.  If you search "arduino microphone jack" you should find plenty of information about this.